# Tensorflow: Graph built with Scan runs slower than graph built with For-Loop

Tags: tensorflow, profiling

I'm implementing an iterative algorithm in tensorflow, and I was surprised to see that a graph generated as a for-loop ran *faster* than a graph generated by scan.  In my code, I have two possible implementations for a function:

Using a For-loop:

```
def multi_step(self, x_data, acts, epsilon, n_iter, beta=None, y_data=None):
    for i in range(n_iter):
        acts = self.step(x_data=x_data, acts=acts, epsilon=epsilon, beta=beta, y_data=y_data)
    return acts
```

Or using scan:

```
def multi_step(self, x_data, acts, epsilon, n_iter, beta=None, y_data=None):
    output = tf.scan(
        fn = lambda last_acts, _: self.step(x_data=x_data, acts=last_acts, epsilon=epsilon, beta=beta, y_data=y_data),
        initializer=acts,
        elems = tf.range(n_iter),
    )
    return[o[-1] for o in output]
```

I've verified that these produce identical results.

As expected, it takes longer to compile the graph with the for loop (and this time scales with the number of iterations).

But what is unexpected is that the for-looped graph runs over 2x faster:

```
Comparing the 20-step versions of loop and scan:
            Graph Building (s)      Initializing Params (s)       Rate (iter/s)
Scan        4.206                   1.6                            34-38
Loop        21.85                   7.5                            84-91
```

It would be nice to have the best of both worlds (fast compilation, fast runtime), and it seems that there is no good reason why it shouldn't be possible.

Has anyone encountered this issue?  Is there an easy fix that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you thought about enabling [eager execution](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/10/eager-execution-imperative-define-by.html)? Doing so transforms TensorFlow into an imperative front-end, and lets you freely mix Python control flow (if statements and for loops) with TensorFlow code.

Comment: Did not know about that and have not tried.  Good suggestion, will try.